# Run custom Django management command over SSH

Tags: python, django, ssh

I have a Django application with a custom management command in one of the apps. If I log in over SSH I can run it without any problems with

> python manage.py sitedir/mycommand

However, if I try to run the command as a oneliner from my local box like this:

> ssh myserver python manage.py sitedir/mycommand

I get an ImportError like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mysite/manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 67, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named mysite.myapp.management.commands.mycommand
```

The real reason is that I want to run this admin command from a Fabric script but until I can get it to run via the ssh one-liner I guess it will be impossible. Is there something in the environment that differs when you run it via the ssh one-liner? The python path seems correct in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a clue what is going on. I don't know how to fix it yet.

To reproduce your scenario I wrote a small script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, django
print django.VERSION
```

After which I executed it after logging in through SSH as well as remotely (`ssh yourserver.com "python /home/me/script.py"`) and everything went fine.

Then I changed the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
print os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']
```

This version worked when I logged in to the server but **failed** when I tried to execute it remotely.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/script.py", line 3, in <module>
    print os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/UserDict.py", line 22, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'
```

Apparently the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable is not set when you execute the command remotely over SSH. I suspect this ***may*** be what is going wrong in your case. You will need to figure out how to make sure that this variable is properly set before executing the script.

<strike>Perhaps you can explicitly set it: `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'foo'`.</strike>.

Try this:

```
ssh yourserver.com "python /home/me/script.py" -t 
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings.custom
```

Comment: I think you are on to something. I have managed to run it via a shell script oneliner like this: 

cd $PROJECTPATH && $HOME/v/bin/python manage.py mycommand --settings=$SETTINGS --pythonpath=$HOME

It seems like a path related issue after all. The environment seems to get screwed up when a user is not logged in properly. Thank you for taking your time to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `mysite` path to sys.path in manage.py? It could help - as I can see now python does not see mysite directory.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('mysite_directory')
```

Comment: That didn't work for me but it feels like it could be related. I am looking at how django-chronograph sets up the environment to see if there are things I can copy.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because the .profile file is not loaded. Try this instead (replace .profile with your shell profile):

```
ssh myserver '. ~/.profile; python manage.py sitedir/mycommand'
```